# Remove multiple lines and following based on string in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, pipe, fasta

I have a (fasta) file `input.fa` that looks like this

```
>coucou
GAGAGATAGTATAGATATATAGGATATATA
>hello_world
GATATATTCTCTCTGAFAGACGACGACFGACTACTACGAC
>ziva_wesh
HAHTAHTAHTAHCGAGAGACAGCAGCAGCACTTACTACATCHBACAHCAHCAHA
```

I would like to get rid of both

```
>coucou
GAGAGATAGTATAGATATATAGGATATATA
```

and

```
>ziva_wesh
HAHTAHTAHTAHCGAGAGACAGCAGCAGCACTTACTACATCHBACAHCAHCAHA
```

What I am doing is (based on [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56123/remove-line-containing-certain-string-and-the-following-line) by @Hai Vu)

```
$awk '/hello/{getline;next} 1' input.fa | awk '/coucou/{getline;next} 1'
>ziva_wesh
HAHTAHTAHTAHCGAGAGACAGCAGCAGCACTTACTACATCHBACAHCAHCAHA
```

Is there a way of doing this (using `awk` or `sed` or `perl` script) without "piping" the first `awk` result into a second `awk` command? (sthg like `/hello&coucou/{getline;next} 1' input.fa`)

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I didn't test the GNU grep solution `egrep -A1 -v "hello|coucou" input.fa`, does this work?

Comment: @ Walter A my output is:
`GAGAGATAGTATAGATATATAGGATATATA
>hello_world
GATATATTCTCTCTGAFAGACGACGACFGACTACTACGAC
>ziva_wesh
HAHTAHTAHTAHCGAGAGACAGCAGCAGCACTTACTACATCHBACAHCAHCAHA`
so it seems that it just removes the first `coucou` occurrence

Answer (score 3):

One simple way:

```
$ awk '/hello/{getline;next} /coucou/{getline;next} 1' input.fa 
>ziva_wesh
HAHTAHTAHTAHCGAGAGACAGCAGCAGCACTTACTACATCHBACAHCAHCAHA
```

Or if you prefer:

```
$ awk '/(hello)|(coucou)/{getline;next} 1' input.fa 
>ziva_wesh
HAHTAHTAHTAHCGAGAGACAGCAGCAGCACTTACTACATCHBACAHCAHCAHA
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! :)

Comment: If you don't want to repeat the `{getline;next}`, you can make a compound regular expression as in the second example just added.

Answer (score 3):

A simple sed command can also handle this:

```
sed -nr '/>(hello|coucou)/{N;d};p' file
>ziva_wesh
HAHTAHTAHTAHCGAGAGACAGCAGCAGCACTTACTACATCHBACAHCAHCAHA
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/>(coucou|ziva_wesh)/,+1d' file
```

This deletes the ranges of 2 lines (the match of the line containing `>coucou` or `>ziva_wesh` and the following line).